# Set spinner in Action-bar in android

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-spinner

**I want to set spinner in action bar so can any one provide me an example for it. How can I do this?**

When entering the page I want the spinner in the action bar to expand programmatically after it's populated with items so the user needs to pick an item. As of now the first item in the adapter is selected automatically.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html. check the topic adding drop down navigation

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Comment: well i read this i want some example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an spinner to the action bar is pretty straightforward as mentioned in the guide here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown

They also have sample code there. Whenever you need to open the spinner programmatically, you can just send it a click event:

```
mySpinner.performClick();
```

Comment: Thanks you have video for it ?

Comment: Video? Sorry. It's pretty easy to try out yourself.